# Type in Array changed when Converting Objective-C Class to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I post a request to get some json data and try to convert the data to Model

```
var newDrugs = Array<DxyDrugInfo>()
newDrugs = self.parseDrugJsonToModels(data) ?? []
private func parseDrugJsonToModels(data: NSData) -> Array<DxyDrugInfo>?{
    let json = JSON(data: data)
    if let drugsArray = json["data"].arrayObject as? Array<[String : AnyObject]>, success = json["success"].bool where success {
        var sortedArray = Array<DxyDrugInfo>()
        for drugDic in drugsArray {
            let drugInfo = DxyDrugInfo()
            drugInfo.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(drugDic)
            sortedArray.append(drugInfo)
        }
        return sortedArray
    }
    return nil
}
```

DxyDrugInfo is a Objective-C Model Class

My question is the sortedArray's type is Array of DxyDrugInfo, and it changed to
[image]
when assigned to newDrugs.
I want to convert it to DxyDrugInfo and I also want to what the type is.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That type you're looking at, `@lvalue [DxyDrugInfo]`, **is** "array of `DxyDrugInfo`". You're already done! The square brackets around a type are shorthand for "array", that is:

```
[DxyDrugInfo] == Array<DxyDrugInfo>
```

and `@lvalue` just means that `newDrugs` is a variable you can assign to. (It's the opposite of "r-value", which is a value you could assign to an "l-value".)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know they are same, but I just curious about why Xcode show "@lvalue" in the debug area which I never see the words before

Comment: I'm not sure--I can't seem to reproduce that behavior in Xcode 8 beta. I believe it's about the *display* of the type, though, not the type itself.